# DataTable with multiple dimensions?

Tags: c#, datatable

I've looked at this heavily and cannot seem to find a way to have multiple tables, each with one "type" (not data type) of data on them.

I basically want to be able to access data related to say "Thing A" across multiple "types" of data. Say one is a name, the other is a favorite color. These belong in separate tables really, they're related by "Thing A", but are not best stored besides each other in the same table. However they both need to be connected back to "Thing A".

I hope this meets the question standards. I don't yet have the vocabulary or knowledge to talk about this in a more efficient way.

Comment: So, instead of a table of values, you want a cube?

Comment: A DataTable has a collection of DataColumns and an array of DataRows. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Steve So I can place `DataRow[][]` under a single column and then look it up via `DataRow["value1"]["value2"]`?

Comment: @juhar, yes a cube

Comment: @hc1 That would just be a list or array of `DataTable`s.  That or you'd have to create your own datastructure.

Comment: Custom data structures are much better suited to this. Then you can easily filter with [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)

Comment: @juharr That can work, I was just hoping to have it be a bit more relational.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I reworded my question a bit so hope it makes some more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my question it appears that I can use a DataSet to contain multiple DataTables, each of which will have one "type" (not data types) of data:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable().TableName = "thisTypeOfData");
dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable().TableName = "someOtherData");

// Assume columns for "Thing A" added to the DataTables.
```

Can then access via:

```
dataSet.Tables["thisTypeOfData"].Column["Thing A"];
dataSet.Tables["someOtherData"].Column["Thing A"];
```

More information on DataSets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeskbwf7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use arrays, like the example in your question, do:
`object[,] o = new object[0,0];`
 And then replace `object` with your object type and `[0,0]` with the number of elements you want in the array.  And to access a single object, of course, do `o[1,1]` or whatever number you want to access.